# "提案された編集" を改善しようとした際に「文章の整え方」の表示位置がおかしい

Tags: バグ, 再現性なし, 編集

レビューキューに編集提案があった場合に、その場で「編集して改善」などを行うと、右脇に表示される
「文章の整え方」がだいぶ画面下の方に表示されてしまいます。(本来なら本文の横辺りに表示されるはず)

本文のフォーム内にもヘルプはありますし、レビューキューにアクセスできるユーザーであればヘルプを参照するまでもないのかもしれませんが、やはり見やすい位置に表示された方がよいのかなと思います。

なお、英語版等でも同じ現象が再現するのか(=日本語版固有の問題なのか)は確認できていません。

**確認環境:**

Windows 10
Opera 71.0

---

**実際の表示例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

再現を試みましたが、現在サイドバーは本来あるべき形でレンダリングされているようです。これまでのある時点で修正されたのではないかと思われます。ただし、この問題が引き続き発生する場合はどうぞお知らせくださいませ。